# Ruby on Rails: Field not holding data on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action, edit

I have an app where the user can submit a new project. After they have submitted one, they have the option to edit the project they have just submitted. When clicking on edit, it brings up the form again, and all the data is shown that had been entered before.

My problem lies with one of the fields, that allows the user to select many technologies. It is linked to another table called `Projecttechnol` that holds the link between the `Technol` table and the `Project` table. When the user clicks the edit button, all the technologies that were held with that project don't show up. If the user clicks a new technology and saves, the new technology is saved, and the old one is still there.

**My edit view for technology:**

```
<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>
  <%= ab.label "Choose Technologies"%> </br>
  <%= collection_select( :technols, :id, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
<% end %>
```

**My Project Controller: with new, edit, create and update actions**

```
def new

  @project = Project.new
  @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

  @all_technols = Technol.all
  tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?


  @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])


@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build


  end

def create  
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @technol.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?

    params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|


    if !tech.empty?

    @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 

end

end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @technol.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?

     params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|

     if !tech.empty?
     @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 

  end
  end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am new to rails, so any help at all will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is my project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :fullname, :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benefits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech , :technols, :technol_tokens

has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :technols, :through => :projecttechnols

accepts_nested_attributes_for(:technols)
```

UPDATE2

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"+Fdh61iVz2IqZ+bNQz9SIa5ly7nNXaiCEr28hVWUxpM=",
 "project"=>{"project_name"=>"Beverly",
 "status"=>"Completed",
 "client"=>"Qtjpa",
 "business_div"=>"Ecbly",
 "project_owner"=>"Qpzrv",
 "start_date"=>"2012-10-15",
 "edited_date"=>"2012-10-08",
 "projecttechnols"=>{"id"=>["",
 "41"]},
 "role"=>"Ozeoe",
 "industry"=>"Wjfiq",
 "summary"=>"Eypriw lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipisicing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
 "lessons_learned"=>"Kbjuhy lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipisicing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
 "customer_benefits"=>"Fsonlw lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipisicing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",,
 "keywords"=>"Bwdtm"},
 "new_client"=>"",
 "new_business_div"=>"",
 "new_project_owner"=>"",
 "new_role"=>"",
 "new_industry"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Save Edit",
 "id"=>"103"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>
  <%= ab.label "Choose Technologies"%> </br>
  <%= collection_select( :technols, :id, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
<% end %>
```

should be like:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:projecttechnols) do |ab| %>
  <%= ab.label "Choose Technologies"%> </br>
  <%= ab.collection_select(:id, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
<% end %>
```

However, `f` should be replaced by the argument you've used for form_for block. Like:

```
form_for(@project) do |f|
```

Also make sure, your `Project` includes correct relationships to the nested model and it has `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I changed my code to yours and I got an error. The technologies still don't show up, and when I try to add more I get this error: `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`. I have updated my question so you can see my model.

Comment: Hi there, I still get the same error. `NoMethodError in ProjectsController#update`, `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`. I have added my params to my question

Comment: please put the code in update method and tell us which line gives the above error!

Answer (score 0):

You have set `:multiple => true` in the `collection_select`.

Comment: I need to allow them to select multiple technologies